# Need help understanding recursion with array sorts

Tags: java, recursion

My task is to write a recursive method called quadSort that splits an array into 4 parts which are sorted by quadSort then the first two (A and B) are merged into one array (X) and the second two (C and D) are merged into one (Y) then those two are merged into one. The quadSort should call quadSort() 4 times (once for each part). My problem is that I have the base case completed but I can't figure out how to write the recursive portion of the method. Can anyone help me understand how to go about this or show me an example? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is my attempt

```
    public static void quadSort(int array[], int index, int length){

    for (int i = 1; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] <= 1000){
            for(i = 1; i<array.length;i++){         //Start point for the insertion sort
                int key = array[i];
                int j = i-1;
                while((i>-1) && (array[j] > key)){
                    array [j+1] = array[j];
                    i--;
                }
                array[j+1] = key;
            }                                       //End insertion sort
        }
        else{
            int split = (array[i])/4;

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please post your existing attempt.

Comment: you said it yourself, you need to start by splitting the array in 4.

Comment: That sounds similar to a MergeSort - the Wikipedia article on merge sort has an example (in C, not java) of a recursively implemented merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weirdly modified mergeSort, where rather than recursing all the way until you get 1-length sub-arrays, and only then starting to merge, you recurse until the sub-array length is 1/4 of the original array length, sort that with whatever sorting algo you'd prefer (quicksort?) and then merge it back up. It is not clear what it is expected if the array does not have at least 4 elements. You can adjust it to whatever you need it to do in that case.

Using pseudocode it would be something like this:

```
quadSort(array, l, r):
    m = array.length/2 - 1
    //First checking if it is the base case 
    // i.e. l and r define one quarter of the array
    if((l == 0 AND r < m) OR //First quarter
       (l > 0 AND r == m) OR //Second quarter
       (l == m+1 AND r < array.length - 1) OR //Third quarter
       (l > m+1 AND r == array.length - 1))   //Fourth quarter
         quicksort(array, l, r) //Base case
    else
         //Not the base case, hence we proceed to further split the array
         //and recurse on quadsort, before proceeding to merge
         m = (r+l)/2
         quadsort(array, l, m)
         quadsort(array, m+1, r)
         merge(array, l, m , r)

merge(array, l, m, r):
    //Standard merge procedure from mergesort
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, the array will have 40,000 elements. That is why the program will have the 4 major splits.